# Need assistance with Providers in Flutter

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm trying to get my head around the Providers in Flutters... but after following some tutorials, I'm still facing some issue.

When I try to run this code, it gives me an error

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this MyHomePage Widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_way/MyHomePageViewModel.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyHomePageViewModel(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Consumer<MyHomePageViewModel>(
                builder: (context, viewModel, child) {
                  return Text(viewModel.text);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () =>
              Provider.of<MyHomePageViewModel>(context, listen: false)
                  .onClicked(),
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
      ),
    );
  }
}



import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class MyHomePageViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  String text = 'Initial text';

  void onClicked() {
    text = 'Something was clicked';
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The website where I found this example use it as

```
Provider.of<MainViewModel>(context, listen: false).onClicked(),
```

But that doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before a widget that needs a provider is presented, it is required you **create** that particular provider before the page is built.

Checkout the working sample of your code below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_way/MyHomePageViewModel.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => MyHomePageViewModel(),
      builder: (_, __) => MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Consumer<MyHomePageViewModel>(
              builder: (context, viewModel, child) {
                return Text(viewModel.text);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () =>
            Provider.of<MyHomePageViewModel>(context, listen: false)
                .onClicked(),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class MyHomePageViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  String text = 'Initial text';

  void onClicked() {
    text = 'Something was clicked';
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: This!! Thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome, if you need to create Many providers for use, you will use `MultiProvider`

Answer (score 0):

In your provider code, do you have a class defined like:

```
class MyHomePageViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  // your stuff here, like getter and setters, methods, etc
}
```

That class will deal with all the centralisation of your states, essentially acting as you'd hope - the provider.